# Find rows in pandas dataframe, where diffrent rows have common values in lists in columns storing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I can solve my task by writing a for loop, but I wonder, how to do this in a more pandorable way.

So I have this dataframe storing some lists and want to find all the rows that have any common values in these lists,

(This code just to obtaine a df with lists:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,1,4,6]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  5
3  B  1
4  B  4
5  C  6
>>> d = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)
```

)

Here we start:

```
>>> d

A       [1, 2]
B    [5, 1, 4]
C          [6]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

I want to select rows with index 'A' and 'B', because their lists overlap by the value 1.

I could write now a for loop or expand the dataframe at these lists (reversing the way I got it above) and have multiple rows copying other values. 
What would you do here? Or is there some way, to use df.groupby(by=lambda x, y : return not set(x).isdisjoint(y)), that compares two rows? 
But groupby and also boolean masking just look at one element at once...

---

I tried now to overload the equality operator for lists, and because lists are not hashable, then of tuples and sets (I set hash to 1 to avoid identity comparison). I then used groupby and merge on the frame with itself, but as it seems, that it checks off the indexes, that it has already matched.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter


class IndexTuple(set):
    def __hash__(self):
        #print(hash(str(self)))
        return hash(1)
    def __eq__(self, other):

        #print("eq ")
        is_equal = not set(self).isdisjoint(other)

        return is_equal

l = IndexTuple((1,7))


l1 = IndexTuple((4, 7))

print  (l == l1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=(10, 2)), columns=['a','b']).reset_index()
d = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(IndexTuple).to_frame().reset_index()

print (d)

print (d.groupby('b').b.apply(list))

print (d.merge (d, on = 'b', how = 'outer'))
```

outputs (it works fine for the first element, but at `[{3}]` there should be `[{3},{0,3}]` instead:

```
True
   a       b
0  0     {1}
1  1  {0, 2}
2  2     {3}
3  3  {0, 3}

b
{1}                  [{1}]
{0, 2}    [{0, 2}, {0, 3}]
{3}                  [{3}]

Name: b, dtype: object
   a_x       b  a_y
0    0     {1}    0
1    1  {0, 2}    1
2    1  {0, 2}    3
3    3  {0, 3}    1
4    3  {0, 3}    3
5    2     {3}    2
```

Comment: Can you start from df, rather than in d ?

Comment: That would be nice, but then I would have to contruct the df some other way. The goal is, that the list/sets/tuples contain indexes, from which one can step to the next row.

Comment: @gwf I see you have unaccepted. If you have follow up questions, would you please write a new post instead of cluttering your question with details that make it difficult to follow? It would be best if separate questions had their own posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `merge` on `df`:

```
v = df.merge(df, on='b')
common_cols = set(
    np.sort(v.iloc[:, [0, -1]].query('a_x != a_y'), axis=1).ravel()
)

common_cols
{'A', 'B'}
```

Now, pre-filter and call `groupby`:

```
df[df.a.isin(common_cols)].groupby('a').b.apply(list)
a
A       [1, 2]
B    [5, 1, 4]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are asking for a "pandorable" solution, but in my opinion this is *not* a task ideally suited to `pandas`.

Below is one solution using `collections.Counter` and `itertools.combinations` which provides your result without using a dataframe.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

data = {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,1,4,6]}

d = defaultdict(set)

for i, j in zip(data['a'], data['b']):
    d[i].add(j)

res = {frozenset({i, j}) for i, j in combinations(d, 2) if not d[i].isdisjoint(d[j])}

# {frozenset({'A', 'B'})}
```

**Explanation**

1. Group to a set with `collections.defaultdict`. via an O(n) complexity solution.
2. Iterate using `itertools.combinations` to find set values which are not disjoint, using a set comprehension.
3. Use `frozenset` (or sorted `tuple`) for key type as lists are mutable and therefore cannot be used as dictionary keys.